# Wordpress - random URLs getting called by some bot

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this Wordpress site which had bbPress plugin installed (basically a forum plugin). Later it was no longer used and flooded by spambots, so I disabled it. There are still calls to random links the forum was in previously (e.g. /forum/tag/{random_string}). They are not getting anywhere as the plugin is no longer active, however, those calls are quite frequent. Should I be worried about them or just leave them be? The site does not seem to be slowed down much or anything. And visitors calling the /forum/ links are from different IP addresses, so blacklisting them all would be quite difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Dismiss those, as long as you are positive they get "404" error and not "200".

Moreover, add

```
Disallow: /forum/
```

to robots.txt so that good bots will forget you.